# Delete a duplicate folder on Github

Tags: windows, git, github

On my github, I have 2 folders with the same name but with one letter uppercase,ie,
I have `problems_folder` and `problems_Folder`.
I want to delete the second one. However, when I clone the repo on my local machine, I see that the contents of both folders are merged into a single folder. (This is possibly because in windows, folder names are case insensitive).
As a result, I am not able to delete one specific folder.
Can anyone give any alternative to this?

Comment: Try [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10